# Web Scraping AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' Error

Tags: attributeerror

I’m trying to make a program that extracts all the food menu from a college and turn it in to a list file, and then turning it into a CSV file. What ever I do, there seems to be a error on line 14 saying : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

```
the code is this:
import requests
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
file = open('급식.csv','a',newline='')
add = []
writer = csv.writer(file)
p = requests.get('https://www.gnu.ac.kr/main/ad/fm/foodmenu/selectFoodMenuView.do')

soup = bs(p.text,"html.parser")
t = soup.select("div > table > thead > tr")

for i in t:
  add.append((str(i).replace('<br>',',')).text.split().text)
writer.writerows(add)
file.close()
```

I am not all the way done, but I want to fix the error write now. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in t:   
  add.append((str(i).replace('<br>',',')).text.split())
```

Don't repeat `.text`